# How to select a function in Neovim using LSP?

Tags: neovim, lsp

I want to select (e.g. to comment/uncomment) entire functions at a time in Neovim using the built-in LSP. I do this now by avoiding empty lines in functions so that I can `vap` to select the entire block, but this does not scale well to larger functions where spaces improve readability. I'd like for the editor to recognize and select entire functions.

How to use Neovim to do this?

Comment: What is the programming language you are using?

Answer (score 1):

`v]M` should select until the end of function.
whether it works correctly, might depends on the language and the exact case.

Some plugins may implement this. Even some syntax files, I think. Another option is to rely upon `]=` to select all lines that are of the same indentation.

```
'jeetsukumaran/vim-indentwise'
```

implements it.

I also think vim-targets has `vaF` to select functions. Not sure about implementation. I don't think it is related directly to LSP, though I might be surprised.